# In Python (BeautifulSoup), how do I prevent a string from being interpreted as scientific notation?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm using BeautifulSoup to parse XML and return a 5-character string. Python is interpreting some of the strings as scientific notation (e.g., 0E001, 1E001), but I need to get the string itself.

I've tried applying str(some_code) and f"{some_code}" in multiple places, but can't seem to figure out how to force Python to interpret the result as a string as opposed to scientific notation. Here are the excerpts of the relevant code:

Function definition:

```
def find_eccn(text:str) -> str:
    """
    This function returns a string with the substring preceding the first whitespace.
    """
    return text[:text.find(" ")]
```

Within main() function:

```
for i in soup.find_all(["P"]):
    # Get text in line and strip extra whitespace.
    line = i.get_text().strip()
    # Parse the line into the string.
    eccn = find_eccn(line)
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Edit: Here's an example of the text within a tag that's causing problems: '1E001 “Technology” according to the General Technology Note for the “development” or “production” of items controlled' - The function is returning 10 instead of 1E001.

Edit 2: Here is the full code:

```
# Import required modules.
from datetime import date
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv

# Define a function to find the ECCN in the CCL.
def find_eccn(text:str) -> str:
    result = text[:text.find(" ")]
    return result

# Define a function to find the ECCN description in the CCL.
def find_eccn_description(text):
    result = text[text.find(" ")+1:]
    return result

# Define a main function which generates a CSV file with CCL data.
def main():
    # Determine today's date.
    today = date(2022, 10, 27)
    # Define the URL to be scraped.
    url = f"https://www.ecfr.gov/api/versioner/v1/full/{today}/title-15.xml?subtitle=B&chapter=VII&subchapter=C&part=774"
    # Initialize a requests Response object.
    page = requests.get(url)
    # Parse the XML data with BeautifulSoup.
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, features="xml")
    # Remove all of the <note> tags.
    for x in soup.find_all("NOTE"):
        x.decompose()
    # Reduce the soup object to only the first <div9> tag.
    reduction = soup.find("DIV9")
    # Define CCL field headers.
    fields = ["classification", "eccn", "eccn_description", "item", "item_description"]
    # Define a list for CCL rows.
    rows = []
    # Loop through the <*insert applicable*> tags in the soup object.
    for i in reduction.find_all(["FP-2"]):
        # Get text in line and strip extra whitespace.
        line = i.get_text().strip()
        # Parse the line into the ECCN and its description.
        eccn = find_eccn(line)
        eccn_description = find_eccn_description(line)
        # Append data to the 'rows' list.
        rows.append(["classification", eccn, eccn_description, "item", "item_description"])
    # Create CSV file and write USML data to it.
    with open(f"ccl_{today}.csv", "w", encoding="utf-8", newline="") as csvfile:
        csvwriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter="|")
        csvwriter.writerow(fields)
        csvwriter.writerows(rows)

# Set main function to run when the file is run.
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: I literally have no idea what you are talking about. Can you provide some examples of expected output you are trying to get?

Comment: The expected output would be "0E001". Instead I'm getting "0".

Comment: please update the post with the function `find_eccn`

Comment: Other examples include "1E001" being converted to "10" and "2E001" being converted to "20". @AlanSTACK

Comment: The find_eccn function is already included, @RJAdriaansen :)

Comment: Nothing here would do what you're describing. The problem lies elsewhere.

Comment: You are converting the `eccn` string to integer or float without showing us.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your code works correctly: It may be that the `1E001` is being parsed into scientific notation by the program used for looking at your `.csv` file (i.e. Excel).

However, from my perspective, it appears that the output `eccn` identifier is correct (unless I'm missing something). Here's a screenshot from the output generated from your posted code:

[image]

You could try inserting a `'` in front of the `eccn` number to ensure that it isn't treated as scientific notation in Excel.

Comment: You're correct; LibreOffice is interpreting 0E001 as 0 (etc). Thanks for bearing with my noob question!